# Purge documents in MongoDB without impacting the working set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

We have a collection of documents and each document has a time window associated to it. (For example, fields like 'fromDate' and 'toDate'). Once the document is expired (i.e. toDate is in the past), the document isn't accessed anymore by our clients.

So we wanted to purge these documents to reduce the number of documents in the collection and thus making our queries faster. However we later realized that this past data could be important to analyze the pattern of data changes, so we decided to archive it instead of purging it completely. So this is what I've come up with.

1. Let's say we have a "collectionA" which has past versions of documents
2. Query all the past documents in "collectionA". (queries are made on secondary server)
3. Insert them to a separate collection called "collectionA-archive"
4. Delete the documents from collectionA that are successfully inserted in the archive
5. Delete documents in "collectionA-archive" that meet a certain condition. (we do not want to keep a huge archive)

My question here is, even though I'm making the queries on Secondary server, since the insertions are happening in Primary, does the documents inserted in archive collection make it to the working set of Primary ? The last thing we need is these past documents getting stored in RAM of Primary which could affect the performance of our live API.

I know, one solution could be to insert the past documents into a separate DB server. But acquiring another server is a bit of hassle. So would like to know if this is achievable within one server.

Comment: Deleting and inserting will pollute the working set no matter what, since MongoDB still needs to load the documents to delete them and insert them into the new collection. How about doing this operation during low traffic hours? Also, are you actually seeing the effect of the working set issue, or are you trying to preempt this situation?

Comment: I’m trying to preempt the situation.. did not see it in action.

Comment: How does it matter if this is done during low traffic hours.. working set would still be polluted and the subsequent requests will be slower right ? Right now I want to find out if inserts and deletes evict the documents in the working set or not. Even if it does, does the advantage of having less documents in the frequently accessed collection outweigh the working set pollution ?

Comment: Have you simulated the workload and see if it is actually detrimental to the operation? If it's slower, is it within a tolerable limit? How much slower is it even with working set pollution? The effect might be smaller than you think.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, the workload you described will result in pollution of the working set. However this is only a theory, and how much the pollution actually affects operation might be just academic since it greatly depends on the actual work, your hardware, the document sizes, etc. If you have the numbers from a simulated workload, there might be more concrete things we can work with.